# Selenium FindElement working for Firefox but not for IE

Tags: c#, selenium

So I am starting to learn automation using Selenium and C#, problem is i can navigate to my facebook, google what ever and all works good on firefox. But when using IE browsers it opens the webpage but then throws error 'NoSuchElementException'.  I am using same code, one works one does not.
here is IE code

```
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\folder");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Hello World");
```

Here is firefox code

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be timing issue on both browser. You should try using more stable code using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is visible before interaction as below :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("q")));
element.SendKeys("Hello World");
```

Comment: IWait does not exist, what package you using for that?

Comment: Follow this https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_IWait_1.htm